# Updating .csv file with updated values using Timer MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, csv, timer

I have a timer which updates a value in my script every minute

```
Period = 60; % Update period in seconds

tim = timer('Period', Period, 'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate',...
    'TimerFcn', 'MyScript');

start(tim)

stop(tim)
```

I want to store the updated value in the next row (same column) of a .csv file every time the timer resets

```
%Writes the current value to 60 mins.csv in row 1, column 1

csvwrite('60 mins.csv',MyValue,0,0);
```

My guess is that i need a counter to increase the row number with each updated value/timer iteration. I want to collect at least 1440 values (a full day).

Any thoughts?

Note: the timer IS supposed to leave the whole script on an infinite loop, just in case anybody was wondering.

Edit: My attempt using Alamakanambra's solution (which doesn't work)

```
%Creates a new csv and writes MyValue to a csv at position 0,0
csvwrite('60 mins.csv',MyValue,0,0);

%Read csv and get csv length
csv = csvread('60 mins.csv'); 
len = length(csv); 


csvwrite('60 mins.csv',MyValue,len+1,0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csvwrite` does not have an append function, so when you do

`csvwrite('60 mins.csv',MyValue,len+1,0);`

It fills the spaces up to `len,0` with empty values and then puts your value after that (depending on how you open the file you may only see a single value at the top, you will see the empty space if you open in Excel or similar).

Instead, use `dlmwrite`.

`dlmwrite('60 mins.csv', MyValue, '-append');`

There is no need to check length or specify row number; this just appends each new value onto the end of the file.  If you wanted to save additional values at each step, say the time and the measurement:

`dlmwrite('60 mins.csv', [time,MyValue], '-append');`

Comment: This has been most helpful. However using `dlmwrite('60 mins.csv', MyValue, '-append');` only updates the value in the first 2 rows only. It doesn't add a 3rd row, 4th row, 5th row etc for the 3rd,4th,5th minute of the timer repeating. Thoughts?

Comment: Nevermind. I removed all instances of csvwrite/dlmwrite and simply used your one line of `dlmwrite('60 mins.csv', MyValue, '-append');` and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check length of your csv and increment current row for writing value:

> ```
> csv = csvread('60 mins.csv'); 
> len = length(csv); 
> csvwrite('60 mins.csv',MyValue,len+1,0);
> ```

**EDIT:**
Ok, now i understand:

> ```
> csvwrite('60 mins.csv',[csv MyValue],0,0);
> ```
>
> or:
>       csvwrite('60 mins.csv',[csv; MyValue],0,0);

Comment: Well I use `csvwrite('60 mins.csv',MyValue,0,0);`to create the initial value and this doesn't work. Your code just moves the value to the next row upon each timer reset.

Comment: Sorry, for better readability I have included my re-attempt using your code. It's in the main body of the thread.

Comment: Now I am confused. What doesnt work? Line with csvwrite? Value is not changing?Timer is not working?

Comment: My script (not included because its too big) updates a value every minute using the timer. I want to add the updated value to a csv file and store the previous value in the same csv file in the line above. I.e value = 4 **add to csv**, **timer runs** new value = 64 **add to csv in row below**, **timer runs** new value = 38 **add to csv in row below** etc etc. Your solution does not do this. It doesn't save the old value.

Comment: Invite me to chat if you are available to help.